# How do I serve a React application from an Spring Boot application?

Tags: spring, reactjs, spring-boot, webpack

I would like to serve the results of the Webpack build of a ReactJS UI application from a Spring Boot server application.

As the Webpack build generates all the assets in a "dist" folder i.e. index.html, bundle.js, etc... Accessed as i.e. http://localhost/index.html

And the Spring Boot application serves the API URLs from i.e. http://localhost/api/xxx

Comment: You can put the contents of the `dist` folder into Spring Boot's `static` folder. I've done it in the past but have to recommend against it. It's a pain for the build process and Tomcat isn't exactly fast at serving static files. It's better to have a reverse proxy (e.g. nginx) in front of your Spring Boot application and deploy the React application directly to a directory served by nginx.

Comment: I would prefer to serve them from Spring, at least for development purposes.

Comment: Good to check too: https://medium.com/@itzgeoff/including-react-in-your-spring-boot-maven-build-ae3b8f8826e

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1. create `.env` file in the root of react project (next to package.json)
2. put `PUBLIC_URL=/nameContextRoot` in `.env` file (name of context root typically is name of war file)
3. build react project `npm run build`

For me it generates its contents in `build` directory of react project

4. copy the **contents** of the build directory to the spring-boot apps `static` directory

`static` directory should be a normal folder in `src/main/resources`

5. clean and rebuild spring boot project and run it
6. Contents are now properly served

**UPDATE**

Spring Boot structure

```
D:.
├───.mvn
│   └───wrapper
├───.settings
├───src
│   ├───main
│   │   ├───java
│   │   │   └───my.java.stuff
│   │   ├───resources
│   │   │   └───static
│   │   │       └───static
│   │   │           ├───css
│   │   │           └───js
│   │   └───webapp
│   └───test
│       └───java
│           └───my.java.tests
├───target
│   ├───classes
│   │   ├───java.classes
│   │   └───static
│   │       ├───css
│   │       ├───js
│   │       └───static
│   │           ├───css
│   │           └───js
│   ├───generated-sources
│   │   └───annotations
│   ├───m2e-wtp
│   │   └───web-resources
│   │       └───META-INF
│   │           └───maven
│   │               └───java.stuff
│   ├───maven-archiver
│   ├───maven-status
│   │   └───maven-compiler-plugin
│   │       └───compile
│   │           └───default-compile
│   ├───rclient-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
│   │   ├───META-INF
│   │   └───WEB-INF
│   │       ├───classes
│   │       │   ├───java stuff
│   │       │   └───static
│   │       └───lib
│   └───test-classes
└───WebContent
    └───META-INF
```

ReactJS project structure

```
D:.
├───build
│   └───static
│       ├───css
│       └───js
├───node_modules
├───public
└───src
    ├───components
    ├───domain
    └───util
```

Your api endpoints will be also served below the context root. They have nothing to do with React.

The hint of @Codo to use a reverse proxy to access the static content is still valid. But here you asked specifically for how to host the react app in a spring boot application.

Comment: This approach didn't work. I removed `PUBLIC_URL=/nameContextRoot` from `.env` and it started working.

Comment: OK thanks for posting this hint. Maybe something in React has changed over time.